# Can't find SciFi TV show (90s+, huge spaceship, crystal-key, pyramid-like droid)

Tags: story-identification, tv

For a few years I have been trying to find a TV show as I think I watched it in the late 90s, maybe 2000-2001. Can't remember the storyline at all. Just a few facts:
1. A huge spacecraft with a young captain and small team who don't even know how big the spaceship is. 
2. The captain broke crystal-key (disc?) which operates that ship, that's why they don't know how big their ship is.
3. There was a droid (pyramid-like), size: from floor to knee. I remember an episode where it was broken and the team found a new one in a warehouse where there were thousands of droids.

Answer (score 4):

Not much to go on, but did it have that distinct 90's Australian childrens scifi feeling?

Snippets from the Australian show "Escape from Jupiter" and its successor "Return from Jupiter" may conceivably fit the description, though I was unable to find a mention of the robot.

Some of the series clothes, props, lighting and especially CGI puts it uncomfortably close to Babylon 5 (See e.g return to jupiter at 0:39). But Babylon 5 was an *adult drama*. Right? Right?

Comment: The glass key breaking could be in the first one at 0:39

Comment: @Mithrandir: The image, out-of-story, is of a condenser commonly used in chemistry laboratories. But yes, as a prop it might have held some significance, seeing as it was put into the trailer.

Comment: Thank you, I will watch it, looks interesting! But that's not what I am looking for (

Comment: There should be pyramid looking like robot, that's for sure.

Answer (score -2):

Space Cases this is exactly what you are looking for. I was also looking for it.

Comment: This answer could use more detail. Like where is the crystal key? The pyramid droid?